# Checking for overflow before casting to Sequence.IndexDistance

Tags: swift, generics, casting, integer, integer-overflow

I'd like to call `Collection`'s

```
func index(_ i: Self.Index, 
           offsetBy n: Self.IndexDistance, 
           limitedBy limit: Self.Index) -> Self.Index?
```

method with a user-supplied offset.

Offset comes in a `UInt`.

How can I check whether casting to `Self.IndexDistance` will succeed, or whether the supplied offset is out of `Self.IndexDistance`'s bounds?

Comment: What about `if uIntOffset.toUIntMax() <   UIntMax(self.count.toIntMax())` ?

Comment: The function is intended to support offsets larger than count. If the offset would bring the index out of range, nil is returned. Using self.count.toIntMax() feels like a workaround, not like a proper solution.

Comment: I don't know if there is a simple method. `IndexDistance` conforms to `SignedInteger` and that protocol requires a `toIntMax()` instance method, but not a `max` type method (even if all integer types have that). Also there is no failable initializer for integers which fails on out-of-range. Some bit manipulations "tricks" using `MemoryLayout<Self.IndexDistance>.size` might work. – But I may be overlooking something.

Comment: Yup. That's where I'm now, too. Swift should be updated to add `max` method to `SignedInteger` . Is there a way I can limit my function to collections whose IndexDistance supports `max`? Can a protocol be introduced that lists all Integer types to have a `max` method, and then use this protocol as a constraint?

Comment: You can define a protocol requiring a `max` method, but you have to declare protocol conformance explicitly for each integer type for which you need it, e.g. `extension Int: HasMax { }`.

Comment: I just noticed that all integer types have `init(exactly:)` initializers which fail on out-of-range. But that does not help either because these are not part of the Integer protocol.

Comment: So, if I add a custom protocol and have all Integer types conform to it via extension at a central location, I could use this as a constraint. Still a workaround, but at least it's generic and not specific to that specific function's semantics.

Do you want to open a proposal over at Swift's Github, or should I do?

Comment: Yes, that works. – Adding `max`, `min` and `init?(exactly:)` to the Integer protocol sounds reasonable to me. Please go ahead and raise that issue at swift-evolution if you want to.